# Conditional formatting of integers using decimal places

Tags: go, floating-point

I have the following situation: I'll be receiving integers and have to format them according to the following rules:

```
10000 -> 100 // removing the last "00"
10010 -> 100.1 // removing the last "0", and adding a decimal place
10011 -> 100.11 // adding two decimal places
```

How this can be done? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf("%g", float64(i)/100)` gives you just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using floating point numbers

Convert the integer number to `float64`, divide it by `100` and use the `%g` verb of the [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package, it removes trailing zeros:

> For floating-point values, width sets the minimum width of the field and precision sets the number of places after the decimal, if appropriate, **except that for %g/%G precision sets the maximum number of significant digits (trailing zeros are removed)**.

To avoid "large" numbers reverting to `%e` scientific notation (numbers with more than the default precision which is 6 for `%g`), specify the width explicitly, something like this:

```
fmt.Printf("%.12g\n", float64(v)/100)
```

Testing it:

```
for _, v := range []int{
    10000, 10010, 10011,
    10000000, 10000010, 10000011,
    10000000000, 10000000010, 10000000011,
} {
    fmt.Printf("%.12g\n", float64(v)/100)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KoWyV7l-1Lx)):

```
100
100.1
100.11
100000
100000.1
100000.11
100000000
100000000.1
100000000.11
```

### Using integers

Without converting to floating point numbers (and relying on the trailing zero removal of `%g`), this is how you could do it using integer arithmetic:

The last 2 digits are the remainder of dividing by 100, the rest is the result of integer division by 100. You can format these 2 numbers depending on the remainder like this:

```
switch q, r := v/100, v%100; {
case r == 0:
    fmt.Println(q)
case r%10 == 0:
    fmt.Printf("%d.%d\n", q, r/10)
default:
    fmt.Printf("%d.%02d\n", q, r)
}
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/kaR8VY1l552).

Comment: Would not `Convert the integer number to float64` cause problems for integers more than 2^54 as the conversion rounds to a nearby encodable `float64`?  In those case, an integer solution solution would work fine.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, convering to `float64` has its problems arising from the representation. There are cases when such big numbers don't come into play, but when they do, the "Using integers" section is a better choice.